# Flutter the image from url of firebase storage is not showing in second class

Tags: flutter

I have get the image from firebase storage. The document snapshots are passing in class where stream is being built means first class, the image is showing in second class, but i have to show image in Hero widget in next class i.e third.

So, in third class the error is:[image]

My code till now is:

navigating from second class to third class

```
Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: '1',
                        child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              //navigateToImage(widget.ds.data['GraphImg']);
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>ImageHero(widget.ds.data['GraphImg'])));
                            },
                            child: 
                            Card(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                              elevation: 8.0,
                              child:
                              Image.network(
                                widget.ds.data['GraphImg'],
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              ),                           )
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Code in Third class

```
Center(
        child:   
        Hero(
            tag: '1',
            child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child:
                PhotoView(
                    imageProvider: 
                    NetworkImage(widget.ds.data['GraphImg'])
                    //AssetImage("images/sg.jpg")
                    )
                    )
                    ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Code -     `widget.ds.data['GraphImg']` is String.

Either - In your Third Class Constructor. Define the `ds` as String.

**OR**

In second Class pass the  `document snapshot`
like - `=>ImageHero(widget.ds)));`

Comment: i checked now, it says 
"message": "The getter 'data' isn't defined for the class 'String'.",

Comment: i passed as widget.ds.data['GraphImg'].toString(), but prob is that in third class it says data isnt defined for class string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188800/discussion-between-jabir-ishaq-and-anmol-majhail).